GeoPandas Coordinate System Transformation (to_crs) inverts Shapefile
Converting the 10m resolution ocean shapefile from Natural Earth to a different projection "inverts" the shapefile ("drying up the ocean"):
import geopandas as gpd
oceans = gpd.read_file('./ne_10m_ocean')

oceans.plot()

Ok, here the ocean is nice and blue 

But converting to another projection, centered in Nigeria (ESRI:102022), we get this:
oceans.to_crs("ESRI:102022").plot()


What is going on here? How can I re-fill the ocean?

Thanks to the hint by Ian Turton, I found a simple solution that uses GeoPandas: I clipped the oceans shapefile to the area I want to plot, thereby avoiding polygons being turned "inside-out":
GeoDataFrame.clip
target_projection = "ESRI:102022"

lower_left = gpd.points_from_xy(
    x = [2.6], # longitude
    y = [5.725311], # latitude
    crs='EPSG:4326' # = WGS 84
)

upper_right = gpd.points_from_xy(
    x = [7.7], # longitude
    y = [9.3], # latitude
    crs='EPSG:4326' # = WGS 84
)

oceans = gpd.read_file('./ne_10m_ocean')

oceans_clipped = oceans.clip(
    mask=[
        lower_left.x[0],
        lower_left.y[0],
        upper_right.x[0],
        upper_right.x[0]
    ]
)



You're right - but I'm re-using the lower_left/upper_right coordinates to define my plot area later on the in the code.

As can be seen from the artefacts crossing the map, you now have some features that cross the anti-meridian, this leads to some of your polygons being inside out and so the wrong parts get coloured in.
You will need to spit any polygon that crosses the "new" anti-meridian (180+/-25) - though in fact the projection you have chosen if only really valid on the continent of Africa. See this GIS Stackexchange question for an example of the process in QGis.
